# Calling function BeforeClose event in VBA not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a protection function to execute before the workbook closes but it's not working. The protection sub works fine on its own but not when called in WorkBook_BeforeClose()

This is the code found in Module 1:

```
Public Sub protect()

Dim index As Integer
index = 1

Do While index <= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(index).Activate
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "README" Then
    ActiveSheet.unprotect
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    ActiveSheet.protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
End If
index = index + 1
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

This is the code found in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, code girl. What do you mean when you say that `it's not working`? Is an error occurring while the code is running or is the code (seemingly) not running at all because the sheets do not get protected? If you assume the latter of the two cases, then I'd insert a `MsgBox` just to be sure (if the code runs or not). Also, how do you trigger the `_BeforeClose` event? Do you close the file (leaving Excel open) or do you close Excel (and how)?

Comment: When I get that kinfd of issue, I insert here and there in my code something like `debug.print now, "Protect"` (or any module name)

Comment: The code isn't running at all. I inserted a message box and it did appear before closing the file but the protection sub still didn't run :/ The BeforeClose event is triggered when you close the file, then it asks if you want to save changes before you close; even if you choose cancel instead of save the code still runs before your prompted to save

Comment: Maybe ThisWorkbook can not reach the protect() code in Module 1. Try copying the protect() code and pasting it into ThisWorkbook.

Comment: The problem is that the `_BeforeClose` event is not reliable. It depends on how you close the file. If you close the file only but not Excel then it should get triggered. If you close Excel (with the `X` or `Alt` + `F4` or killing the process in the task manager) then this event might get triggered. Yet, it is not certain to happen. But you are saying that an insererted `MsgBox` was shown. So, the sub is called and running (in contrary to what you commented above). It is just that the code is not doing what you expect it to do. Is that right? If so, please tell us what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem with a protect sub as well. Turns out dev1998 was correct and the workbook had trouble finding the sub. Try using:
"Call Module1.Protect", or instead of Module1, whichever module your protect sub is in

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make (some?) changes to a worksheet in or from the Workbook_BeforeClose module.  I've never read it anywhere, but it appears that once this event is triggered, Excel looks the sheets.

I had an unprotected sheet.  It had *never* been protected.  But when I tried to add a timestamp to it from the Workbook_BeforeClose module I got the "protected worksheet" error.

It was also a hidden sheet, so I tried to make it visible so I could verify it was indeed unprotected.  I could not do so either via code or from the properties box.

What I ended up doing was moving my clean-up routines from Workbook_BeforeClose to Workbook_Open and never had anymore problems.